# Local vba array will not export correctly to worksheet

Tags: arrays, vba

I can successfully modify the input array in a local array (B). After running the line "ShiftVector = B", the locals window will show that "ShiftVector" array now contains the contents of B. But after that, the function will just show the first value of the new array "hey" in all 9 cells.

Input is ShiftVector(A1:A9,3)
nr = 9

```
Function ShiftVector(rng As Range, n As Integer) As Variant
Dim nr As Integer, i As Integer
Dim B() As Variant
nr = rng.Rows.Count
ReDim B(nr) As Variant
For i = 1 To nr - n
    B(i) = rng(i + n)
Next i
For i = (nr - n + 1) To nr
    B(i) = rng(i - nr + n)
Next i
ShiftVector = B
End Function
```

expected output is 
hey
3
9
7
yo
2
1
hi
5

However excel is giving me
hey
hey
hey
hey
hey
hey
hey
hey
hey

Comment: ShiftVector = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(B)  ?

Comment: that was it! thank you!